# complexity -big O notation , theta and omega

Tags: complexity-theory, big-o

can anyone help me verifying the following complexities:

```
    10^12 = O(1)?
    2^(n+3) + log(n) = O(2^n)?
    f(n) = Omega(n) and f(n) = theta(n) <=> f(n) = O(n)
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The first two are right, the last is wrong.

In particular, any value that has no variable attached will be "a constant" and therefore O(1). As for why you're correct on the second, 2^n strictly beats log(n) asymptotically, and 2^(n+3) is equivalent to 8*2^n, or O(1)*O(2^n), and it's generally best to simplify big-O notation to the simplest-looking correct form.

The third condition is wrong because f(n) = O(n) does not imply either of the first two statements.

Comment: first I should say that "no" it's not a hw, I'm reading for exam 
second is that I hesitate if that is correct just for theta(1) or theta(2^n)

Comment: Theta(foo) means that something is O(foo) **and** Omega(foo). Both of the functions above have the Theta bounds you just mentioned, along with the O bounds in your original post (also Omega(1) and Omega(2^n) bounds).

Comment: and can u tell me about the last one too? I say it's true

Comment: Uhm. is that supposed to say Omega(n), and not omega(n)? It is impossible for f(n) = Theta(n) and f(n) = omega(n) to be true at the same time. It's going to be false either way--f(n) = O(n) is not a sufficient condition for either of the left-side statements. I'll update my answer to reflect that.